# EhCache replication fully described in Java class doesn't work

Tags: java, tomcat, replication, ehcache

I'm trying to synchronize caches of 2 WAR-s - *A.war* and *B.war*. They are deployed on one Tomcat. Each WAR contains next bean with *init*-method:

```
@Autowired 
public class CacheService {

    enum Cache {CACHE_1, CACHE_2};

    @Autowired
    private String cachePort;

    public void init() throws Exception {
        Configuration config = new Configuration();

        FactoryConfiguration providerConfig = new FactoryConfiguration();
        providerConfig.setClass("net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory");
        providerConfig.setPropertySeparator(",");
        providerConfig.setProperties("peerDiscovery=automatic,multicastGroupAddress=230.0.0.1,multicastGroupPort=4446");
        config.addCacheManagerPeerProviderFactory(providerConfig);

        FactoryConfiguration listenerConfig = new FactoryConfiguration();
        listenerConfig.setClass("net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListenerFactory");
        listenerConfig.setPropertySeparator(",");
        listenerConfig.setProperties("hostName=localhost,port=" + cachePort);
        config.addCacheManagerPeerListenerFactory(listenerConfig);

        CacheConfiguration defaultConfig = new CacheConfiguration();
        defaultConfig.setTimeToLiveSeconds(120);
        defaultConfig.setDiskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds(120);
        defaultConfig.setMemoryStoreEvictionPolicy("LRU");
        defaultConfig.setStatistics(true);
        defaultConfig.setMaxBytesLocalHeap(MemoryUnit.MEGABYTES.toBytes(1));
        config.setDefaultCacheConfiguration(defaultConfig);

        cacheManager = new CacheManager(config);
        for (Cache cache : Cache.values()) {
            cacheManager.addCache(cache.name());
            net.sf.ehcache.Cache createdCache = cacheManager.getCache(cache.name());
            createdCache.getCacheConfiguration().setTimeToLiveSeconds(600);
            createdCache.getCacheEventNotificationService().registerListener(new RMIAsynchronousCacheReplicator(true, true, true, true, true, 5000, 1000));
        }
    }
}
```

*A.war*: **cachePort**=40001
*B.war*: **cachePort**=40002

But caches are not synchronized. Maybe parameters somewhere in RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory, RMICacheManagerPeerListenerFactory or in RMIAsynchronousCacheReplicator are wrong.

Could anyone help, please?

And also, if possible, could anyone describe case when these 2 WAR-s deployed on different tomcats on 2 machines in 1 subnetwork?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect:

```
hostname=localhost
```

you can verify it by checking hearbeats (turn on `net.sf.ehcache.distribution log4j`).
The hostname should be real IP address, not `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But finally I preferred the way with configuration of cache in XML-file.

Comment: hmm.. I did not quite get what you said. In your XML file you have "hostName=127.0.0.1". This will have ehcache RMI listen to itself on each host instead of listening to other hosts because each host will broadcast their caches as 127.0.0.1/cacheName. So if on each server you change this value from 127.0.0.1 to the real IP of that host and restart tomcat that server will start broadcasting its real address so the other servers will properly see it

Comment: I see. Actually both applications run on the same server. I moved configuration from Java-class to _ehcache.xml_. Something like this:                                                         `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache...
<cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory...
<cacheManagerPeerListenerFactory class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListenerFactory"
                                     properties="hostName=localhost, port=40001, socketTimeoutMillis="/> ...`                                                                 Replication works correct.